# Database query to get decimal value in Joomla 2.5

Tags: database, joomla2.5

I'm trying to make a query to a database in Joomla 2.5. I have a db named 'example', and I'm trying to get certain value named 'value' (very original) for a user whose id is 949:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$user = 949;
$db->setQuery( 'SELECT value FROM example WHERE user_id = ' . $user ); 
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
echo $result;
```

However, I'm just getting 'Array' as result (the expected value is a decimal, e.g. 4.5).

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$user = 949;
$db->setQuery( "SELECT value FROM example WHERE user_id = '" . $user."'" ); 
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
echo $result;
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

`$db->loadObjectList()` returns an array of objects, which echo can't display. If you want to just return one value from one row, user `$db->loadResult()` instead.